# Exclude range within random range between negative and positive float. c# unity

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine, floating-point, negative-number

Have a variable that I give a random range between `-2.0f` and `2.0f` (`Random.Range(-2.0f, 2.0f`); in Unity/C#), but I don't want it to pick a number between `-0.6f` and `0.6f`.

How do I got about doing this?

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

Comment: Put it in a loop and break once it generates a value you like?

Comment: @M.Babcock That seems kind of wasteful.  Why not generate two random numbers from two allowable ranges, then randomly select which of the two random numbers to return?

Comment: care to elaborate? or give a more practical example in code? (pretty new to this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop thing seems kind of wasteful to me.  After all, you could end up generating a bunch of unusable numbers.  Why not generate two numbers from the two allowable ranges, then select at random one to return?

```
var candidates = new[] {Random.Range(-2.0f, -0.6f), Random.Range(0.6f, 2.0f)};
return candidates.OrderBy(c => Random.Next()).First();
```

You could also do one random number and then decide at random if you should return it as a negative or positive number.  The code below also avoids the OrderBy method, which I am informed will not work with Unity and iOS

```
var rand = Random.Range(0.6f, 2.0f);
if (Random.Range(0, 100) <= 50)
{
  rand = rand * -1f;
}
return rand;
```

Also, though it is, strictly speaking, outside the scope of your original question, if you cannot assume that both ranges are the same (in absolute values), and you also cannot use OrderBy, you could write something like this:

```
var candidates = new[] {Random.Range(-2.0f, -0.6f), Random.Range(0.6f, 2.0f)};
var idx = Random.Range(0,2); // this should give you either 0 or 1
return candidates[idx];
```

Comment: `OrderBy` should not be used in the current version of unity because this code will fail on iOS.

Comment: @Programmer Whoops.  Never actually worked with Unity.  The second sample now avoids it.

Comment: You second answer is very clever. It looks like you genetare one side then flip it  to the opposite sign. What if the random numbers are instead -2 to 4 instead of -2.0f and 2.0f. Will this still work?

Comment: @Programmer I don't see why not, as long as the negative and positive ranges are for the same absolute values.

Comment: Just tried `var rand = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.6f, 4.0f);` and didn't work. I think your solution is short and I am trying to understand how to make it work with other numbers. what else do I have to change to make work with -2 to 4 ?

Comment: @Programmer Well, in what way does it not work?  Do you get an error?

Comment: NVM I forgot to put `Debug.Log`. It does work.  One last question ...What if both excludes are not thesame number (-0.6 and 0.6) with the signs flipped? For example, how do you  exclude from -2 to 1.f?

Comment: Nice. That's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var delta = Random.Range(-1.4f, 1.4f);
var result = delta >= 0 ? delta + 0.6f : delta - 0.6f;
```

Or perhaps:

```
var delta = Random.Range(-1.4f, 1.4f);
var abs = Mathf.Abs(delta);
var sign = Mathf.Sign(delta);

var result = sign*(0.6f + abs);
```

**EDIT**: Changed things around to avoid using the ternary operator and removed a remark that was wrong. Thanks [@sh1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2417578/sh1)!

Comment: i think this is best answer.

Comment: Try `result = delta + copysignf(0.6f, delta);` to eliminate the ternary, which may be implemented as an unpredictable branch.  Does C# have `copysign()`?

Comment: Also, you'll never get exactly `-0.6f` with _any_ code, because that value can't be represented in binary.

Comment: @sh1 Nope, we don't have `copysign()` in C#. But this is Unity3d scripting if I understand correctly, so we can use [Mathf.Sign](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Sign.html)

Answer (score 1):

Casey's answer looks fine. I just don't know how to make it work with other values. The answer below provides a re-usable code that will easily work with other values.

It generates the first number. That number it will use to determine if it should generate a number **below** the min number you want to exclude or a number **above** the max number you want to exclude. The second number it generates is the actual random number.

```
 float Range(float min, float max, float ignoreFrom, float ignoreToEnd)
 {
     int dirRand = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3); //1 to 2 random number
     float finalRandomNum = 0;

     //If 1, generate number below ignoreFrom, min
     if (dirRand == 1)
     {
         ignoreFrom += 0.00001f; //To make make ignoreFrom exclusive (Remove if you want to include it)
         finalRandomNum = UnityEngine.Random.Range(ignoreFrom, min);
     }

     //If 2, generate number above ignoreToEnd
     else if (dirRand == 2)
     {
         ignoreToEnd += 0.00001f; //To make make ignoreToEnd exclusive (Remove if you want to include it)
         finalRandomNum = UnityEngine.Random.Range(ignoreToEnd, max);
     }
     return finalRandomNum;
 }
```

To test it lets generate 80 random numbers between `-2.0f` and `2.0f` with exclusion min `-0.6f` and max `0.6f`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
{
    Debug.Log(Range(-2f, 2f, -0.6f, 0.6f));
}
```